# Pass Multiple Fixtures into a Test Case

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm passing two fixtures setup_registered_consultant and setup_registered_customer into my test case but the last argument setup_registered_customer isn't being recognized. My test case fails here `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + registered_response2.json()['token_key']` with the error `test_userdetail_logged_in_customer_accesses_consultant_user_detail_view_success - KeyError: 'token_key'`

```
def test_userdetail_logged_in_customer_accesses_consultant_user_detail_view_success(db, client, setup_registered_consultant, setup_registered_customer):
    registered_response = setup_registered_consultant
    registered_response2 = setup_registered_customer

    userdetail_response = client.get(path=reverse('user-detail', args=(str(registered_response.json()['id']),)),
                                      HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + registered_response2.json()['token_key'])
    assert userdetail_response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

**How can I pass multiple fixtures through a test case?**

Edited:

```
@pytest.fixture
def setup_registered_customer(db, client):
    client.post(path=reverse('auto-signup-anonymous-user'),
                   data={"device_serial": "device1", "device_brand": "Apple",
                         "device_version": "1.0", "device_country": "US"})
    response = client.post(path=reverse('register'),
                            data={"device_serial": "device1", "username": "registereduser1",
                                    "email": "registereduser1@example.com", "password": "12345678"})
    return response

@pytest.fixture
def setup_registered_consultant(db, client):
    client.post(path=reverse('auto-signup-anonymous-user'),
                   data={"device_serial": "device1", "device_brand": "Apple",
                         "device_version": "1.0", "device_country": "US"})
    response = client.post(path=reverse('register'),
                            data={"device_serial": "device1", "username": "registereduser1",
                                    "email": "registereduser1@example.com", "password": "12345678"})
    get_user_model().objects.filter(username="registereduser1").update(is_consultant=True)
    ConsultantProfile.objects.create(user=get_user_model().objects.get(username="registereduser1"))
    return response
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `setup_registered_customer`? I'm pretty sure you can pass as many fixtures as you want, exactly as in your code. I would guess the `KeyError` means that there's rather something wrong with the fixture itself that the response doesn't contain the expected key.

Comment: See post again. I keep getting this error if I switch setup_registered_consultant in place of setup_registered_customer. Last argument always fails regardless whether its consultant or customer...If I switch last two arguments, this part fails args=(str(registered_response.json()['id'])

Comment: I think the last argument always fails because you assign it to `registered_response2`, and `registered_response2` is the thing you're trying to extract `token_key` from, and apparently that is not present in the response. Maybe try printing the whole response at the top of the test or inside the fixture to verify?

Comment: Fixed it. My setup_registered_consultant username/email conflicted with setup_registered_customer username and email . I just had to give setup_registered_consultant a different username/email. You can write it in the answer's section and I'll select your answer as best answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test case should accept any number of fixtures on the argument list, and the ordering doesn't matter. Your code looks perfectly correct in this regard.

`KeyError: 'token_key'` suggests that there might be something wrong with variable `registered_response2`, i.e. the JSON apparently doesn't contain the "token_key" key, so ultimately this would mean a problem with the fixture itself, and not with the way it is passed to the test case function.
As discussed in the question comments, this was indeed the case here: server was returning an unexpected response due to a conflict on the backend size, which was caused by how the server was called by the fixture.